# Static image rotation in OpenLayers3 and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, openlayers, openlayers-3, angular-openlayers

I am using [angular-openlayers-directive](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-openlayers-directive) for creating custom map. Tried to modify [this example](http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-openlayers-directive/examples/070-view-rotation-example.html) , used static image instead of maps in custom layers. Bug it goes to error.

I am looking for solution of rotation of custom image as map. Can you please help on this.

Comment: What error? What changes did you try to make?  It's unlikely that you'll get an answer with the information provided so far, even with the bounty.

Comment: What projection are you using for the static image? Is the map loading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your code or knowing the error message is it is hard to say specifically what the problem is, but here's the example modified to rotate a static image:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demoapp">

<head>
  <script src="https://tombatossals.github.io/angular-openlayers-directive/bower_components/openlayers3/build/ol.js"></script>
  <script src="https://tombatossals.github.io/angular-openlayers-directive/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://tombatossals.github.io/angular-openlayers-directive/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  <script src="https://tombatossals.github.io/angular-openlayers-directive/dist/angular-openlayers-directive.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://tombatossals.github.io/angular-openlayers-directive/bower_components/openlayers3/build/ol.css" />
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('demoapp', ['openlayers-directive']);
    app.controller('DemoController', ['$scope', '$http', 'olData', function($scope, $http, olData) {

      angular.extend($scope, {
        degrees: 0,
        center: {
          coord: [900, 600],
          zoom: 3
        },
        defaults: {
          view: {
            projection: 'pixel',
            extent: [0, 0, 1800, 1200],
            rotation: 0
          }
        },
        static: {
          source: {
            type: "ImageStatic",
            url: "http://blog.wallpops.com/wp-content/upLoads/2013/05/WPE0624.jpg",
            imageSize: [1800, 1200]
          }
        },
        view: {
          extent: [0, 0, 1800, 1200],
          rotation: 0
        }

      });

      $scope.degreesToRadians = function() {
        $scope.view.rotation = parseFloat($scope.degrees, 10).toFixed(2) * (Math.PI / 180);
      };

      $scope.$watch('view.rotation', function(value) {
        $scope.degrees = ($scope.view.rotation * 180 / Math.PI).toFixed(2);
      });
    }]);
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="DemoController">
  <openlayers ol-center="center" ol-defaults="defaults" ol-view="view" custom-layers="true" height="400px">
    <ol-layer ol-layer-properties="static"></ol-layer>
  </openlayers>
  <h1>View rotation example</h1>
  <p>You can interact with the view rotation of your map.</p>

  <p>
    <input type="range" min="-180" max="180" ng-change="degreesToRadians()" ng-model="degrees" /> Degrees: {{ degrees }}</p>
  <pre ng-bind="view | json"></pre>
</body>

</html>
```

And the same example in Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/zw7QUyFfWXqnNE9rkdjZ?p=preview